# How can I make a header with a fixed position?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make the position of a header fixed when the top equals 0%?~
For example, the header top value starts at 20%, we scroll down and it reaches the value of 0% then stays fixed.

I can only use HTML/CSS.

Comment: think you would need js for this to calculate your scroll position

Comment: Can't be done without javascript

Comment: It's probably possible without, but it would mean an absolute load of layers of absolutely and fixed positioned masks etc, not worth it, just use js.

Comment: But i can't use :( I just wanted to try with css/Html..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the new proposed property `position: sticky;` currently only supported in Firefox and prefixed in Safari. See [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=position%3Asticky) for more info on browser support.

From the [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-position/#sticky-pos):

> A stickily positioned box is positioned similarly to a relatively positioned box, but the offset is computed with reference to the nearest ancestor with a scrolling box, or the viewport if no ancestor has a scrolling box.
>
> Specifically, once a box has been laid out according to the normal flow or floated, its sticky offset is computed as described below. Offsetting a box (B1) in this way has no effect on the box (B2) that follows: B2 is given a position as if B1 were not offset and B2 is not re-positioned after B1’s offset is applied. This implies that sticky positioning may cause boxes to overlap. However, if sticky positioning causes an 'overflow: auto' or 'overflow: scroll' box to have overflow, the user agent must allow the user to access this content (at its offset position), which, through the creation of a scrolling mechanism, may affect layout.

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/gv9ugaw9/1/)**

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

body * {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #000;
}

.header span {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

.placeholder {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
}

.slider {
    background: #006264;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"><span>This is a header</span></div>
<div class="placeholder">This div holds place</div>
<div class="slider">This should slide up and then stick.</div>
<div class="placeholder">This div holds place</div>
<div class="placeholder">This div holds place</div>
<div class="placeholder">This div holds place</div>
<div class="placeholder">This div holds place</div>
```

Comment: It seems that it would result, the problem is that since it's not available in many browsers I can't use it >.>

Comment: @DinisFigueira Yes, I just wanted to provide an answer to the question above. The effective way to do this currently is to use JavaScript. However, stay tuned to this answer as time goes on, because `position: sticky` will most likely be better supported in the future. Chrome already supported it but had to remove it so that they could optimize it and add it back in later, and once a property works on Firefox and Chrome these days, it's practically guaranteed to stick around and be used by devs.